# Como crear un componente contenedor de otro component en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Puedo crear componentes como:

```
const Route = ({url,clase,contenido}) => { <a className={clase} href={url}>{contendido}<a/>}
```

Y posteriormente hacer lo siguiente:

```
Class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route
        url={una_url}
        clase={una_clase}
        contenido={<i class="fa fa-users">Clikeame<i/>}
      />
     );
   }
  }
```

Pero el contenido no deberia de ir de esa forma, deberia ser algo asi.

```
Class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route
        url={una_url}
        clase={una_clase}
      >
         <i class="fa fa-users">Clikeame<i/>
      <Route/>
     );
   }
 }
```

Que debo de hacer para llegar a este resultado?

```
const Route = ({url,clase}) => { <a className={clase} href={url}>...que debo de hacer aqui? <a/>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{props.children}
```

Cualquier cosa que esté dentro de un componente hasta su cierre es un nodo hijo.

```
<Padre> <Hijo /> </Padre>
```

Usted debió haberse dado cuenta que está intentando crear un HOC. High Order Component, y de esta manera no está haciendo un correcto retorno del mismo.

```
function Route(props){
    const { url, clase, children } = props;
    return (<a className={clase} href={url}> {children} <a/>)
}
```

Le invito a usar más a menudo la instrucción **function** para crear sus componentes.